# R: is there any way that I can automatically update my R in Windows?

Tags: r

Yeah, I am too lazy to download the pack of the newest version. I want to know how to set my R, or is there some code that I can automatically update my R in Windows. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will help you to solve your problem:)

```
# installing/loading the package:
if(!require(installr)) { 
install.packages("installr"); require(installr)} #load / install+load installr

# using the package:
updateR() # this will start the updating process of your R installation.  It will check for newer versions, and if one is available, will guide you through the decisions you'd need to make.
```