# Extracting result of glmer() function in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, logistic-regression

I want to simulate data from Multilevel Logistic Distribution 1000 time and each time estimating parameter and compute the average of the estimates . But it seems , in `glmer()` function results cannot be extracted like `lm()` function , say , `lm(y~x)$coef` . How can I extract the results from `glmer()` function ?

Here is the R code :

```
#Simulating data from multilevel logistic distribution 

library(mvtnorm)
library(lme4)

set.seed(1234)

## J               = number of groups
## n               = group size
## g00,g10,g01,g11 = fixed effect parameters .
## s2_0,s2_1,s01   = variance values for the group level random effect .

simu <- function(J,n,g00,g10,g01,g11,s2_0,s2_1,s01){

  n_j <- rep(n,J)     ## number of individuals in jth group
  N <- sum(n_j)       ## sample size

  #Simulate the covariate value for this sample size .
  z <- rnorm(J)
  x <- rnorm(N)

  #Generate (u_0j,u_1j) from a bivariate normal .
  mu <- c(0,0)
  sig <- matrix(c(s2_0,s01,s01,s2_1),ncol=2)
  u <- rmvnorm(J,mean=mu,sigma=sig,method="chol")

  #Now form the linear predictor .
  pi_0 <- g00 +g01*z + u[,1]
  pi_1 <- g10 + g11*z + u[,2]

  eta <- rep(pi_0,n_j)+rep(pi_1,n_j)*x

  #Transform back to the probability scale .
  p <- exp(eta)/(1+exp(eta))

  #Simulate a bernoulli from each individual distribution .
  y <- rbinom(N,1,p)

  # estimating parameters 

  sim_data_mat <- matrix(c(y,x,rep(z,n_j),rep(1:30,n_j)),ncol=4)
  sim_data <- data.frame(sim_data_mat)
  colnames(sim_data) <- c("Y","X","Z","cluster")

  res <-summary(glmer(Y~X*Z+(1|cluster),family=binomial,data=sim_data,nAGQ=10))
  res$coef
}


out <- replicate(10,simu(30,5,-1,.3,.3,.3,.13,1,0))
##Error in res$coef : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

How can I extract the results from `glmer()` function ?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lme4_0.999999-0  Matrix_1.0-1     lattice_0.20-10  mvtnorm_0.9-9994

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.14.0   nlme_3.1-102  stats4_2.14.0 tools_2.14.0
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Works fine for me and returns the table of coefficients along with std error, z value, p-value etc.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee I don't want all results . Rather I want to extract only coefficients from the output . And the error occurs when I ran the code `summary(glmer(Y~X*Z+(1|cluster),family=binomial,data=sim_data,nAGQ=10))$coef` . It says `$ operator not defined for this S4 class`

Comment: @Pascal But , the code reproduces error when i ran the code `summary(glmer(Y~X*Z+1|cluster),family=binomial,data=sim_data,nAGQ=10))$coef`

Comment: You mean `summary(glmer(Y~X*Z+(1|cluster),family=binomial,data=sim_data,nAGQ=10))$coef`? There is a typo in your comment just above mine. It works for me. Please post the output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: @Pascal Do you get only coefficients ? Where am I doing mistake ? `summary(glmer(Y~X*Z+(1|cluster),family=binomial,data=sim_data,nAGQ=10))$coef`
`Error in summary(glmer(Y ~ X * Z + (1 | cluster), family = binomial, data = sim_data,  : 
  $ operator not defined for this S4 class`

Comment: @Cynderella the code works for me as well, I cannot reproduce the error. But the line you are pasting in this comment does not occur exactly in your code above. Could you edit your question to show the exact code you're running? Ensure that if you restart your R session, then run the exact script that you show us, that you get the same error.

Comment: Yes it works. Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your original post. I use R v 3.2.1 and lme4_1.1-8.

Comment: @DavidRobinson It is the exact one-liner than the 2-line code of the original post.

Comment: Also , I tried this `res <-summary(glmer(Y~X*Z+(1|cluster),family=binomial,data=sim_data,nAGQ=10))`
      `res$coef`
`>Error in res$coef : $ operator not defined for this S4 class`

`names(res)`
`NULL`

Comment: But in case of `lm()` function if I write `names(lm(y~x))` , I found [1] "coefficients"  "residuals"     "effects"       "rank"         
 [5] "fitted.values" "assign"        "qr"            "df.residual"  
 [9] "xlevels"       "call"          "terms"         "model"

Comment: Post the output of `sessionInfo()` please.

Comment: @Pascal I know: my concern is that if that line has been changed, we don't know what else may have

Comment: Very old version of R. Please upgrade everything.

Comment: @Pascal How to upgrade ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082555/r-is-there-any-way-that-i-can-automatically-update-my-r-in-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In mixed-effects models you have two types of coefficients (hence "mixed"): fixed and random. Both can be extracted from lmer/glmer objects using the dedicated functions. For example:

```
lmer_obj = glmer(Y ~ X1 + X2 + (1|Subj), data = D, family = binomial)
fixef(lmer_obj) ## returns fixed effects 
ranef(lmer_obj) ## returns random effects
```

Comment: ... and `getME(lmer_obj,"theta")` or `VarCorr(lmer_obj)` for the variance-covariance parameters or variance-covariance matrix/matrices respectively

Comment: @I used `glmer()` , not `lmer()` . What is `lmer_obj`? Is it  `lmer_obj=lmer()` ? or , `lmer_obj=glmer()'  ?  If  `lmer_obj=glmer()'  ,  then         `fixef()`  , `ranef()` doesn't work .

Comment: By `getME(lmer_obj,"theta")` I get standard deviation of random intercept . Could you please tell  how can I get standard deviation of residual ?