# Updating R in Windows

Tags: r

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082555/r-is-there-any-way-that-i-can-automatically-update-my-r-in-windows) and also [this link](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/) , I tried to update my R version .

```
 sessionInfo()
 R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)
 Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

 locale:
 [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
 [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
 [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
 [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
 [1] installr_0.9

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tools_2.14.0
```

But when I ran the code

```
  updateR()
  Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

It shows exactly the same error while running the following command :

```
 check.for.updates.R() # tells you if there is a new version of R or not.
 Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

 install.R() # download and run the latest R installer
 Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

How can I update my R version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URLs of the `installr` package are probably out of date. Just [go the R website](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/) and download the latest version.

You will have to reinstall your packages manually though, which can be a pain. You can use `rownames(installed.packages())` in your old R to get a list of the packages you currently have installed so that when you go to your new R you can just work down the list and install them all again.

You could even do

```
sprintf('install.packages(%s)', paste(shQuote(rownames(installed.packages())),collapse=','))
```

and then copy-paste that command into your new R to try reinstall everything you had installed on your old R. I personally prefer though to just install them as I need them, so that if I had packages I no longer use in the old R, I don't bother to reinstall them on the new R unless I need them.

Also, the above may fail simply because your current R is quite old compared to the new R so some packages may no longer be compatible.

Answer (score 36):

Per https://github.com/talgalili/installr/#troubleshooting,

Try running:

```
setInternet2(TRUE)
```

That worked for me when I was getting the below error message:

> Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Comment: For some reason, I had to run `setInternet2(TRUE)` two times but it worked for me. +1!

Comment: This solution worked for me first time when updating from 3.2.1 to 3.2.2.